# How to cover all chart area in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Who can help me to expand plot vertically to cover all chart area in winforms application? See screenshot. Thank you so much for answers.

[image: http://shot.qip.ru/00Lyda-6vwdt6pwb/]

Comment: probably missing screenshot?

Comment: i couldn't add screenshot because my reputation is only 4. I'm new user here.

Comment: The real question is: What did you do to create that large area at the bottom?? Did you maybe add an extra `ChartArea`?? There is on `ChartArea`, one `Series` and one `Legend` there by default. Either use these or `Clear` them!

Comment: Thank you for idea! I really added extra chart area. I fixed this and now all works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is: What did you do to create that large blank area at the bottom?

It looks as if you have added an extra `ChartArea`..?

There is one `ChartArea`, one `Series` and one `Legend` there by default.

Either use these or `Clear` them!

I usually create all my `Series` myself and also a short name reference to the `ChartAreas[0]` default area..

Comment: Thank you so much TaW, your answer really helped me.